# I have a problem with regex coincidences with a slash

Tags: regex, .htaccess, redirect

This is the first time I've posted in years of browsing the site. This time I have not managed to find how I can do this redirect in htaccess.

I have the following URL's:

```
domain.com/es/category/product1
domain.com/es/product1
```

And I want to redirect to:

```
domain.es/category/product1
```

I have tried this:

```
Redirectmatch 301 ^/es/(.*)product1 https://domain.es/category/product1
```

And

```
Redirectmatch 301 ^/en/(.*)/product1 https://domain.es/category/product1
```

The question is how to set it to catch everything between /en/ and product1 . Either letters or slash.

Answer (score 1):

With your shown attempts, please try following htaccess rules file. Make sure to put this rule at the top of your htaccess file(considering that you may have other rules which are doing rewriting of URLs here). Make sure to keep your htaccess file in same path along with `es` folder.

Please make sure to clear your browser cache before testing your URLs.

```
##Enabling rewrite engine here.....
RewriteEngine ON
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?(domain)\.com$ [NC]
##Doing redirect of uris which starts from es may/may not have category after it and redirecting to as per OP's requirement.
RewriteRule ^(es)/(?:category/)?product1/?$ http://%1.$1/category/product1 [NC,L,R=301]
```